# how to put multidimensional array in shared preferences in android

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, sharedpreferences

basically my array is in this format an i want to store this in shared preferences
but dont know how  will someone give me idea or code

i am working with dynamic content

```
String[][] my_date;
my_date = new String[][] {
                {"14","26"},
                {"12","16","24","27"},
                {"17"},
                {"8","13","18"},
                {"14"},
                {},
                {"29"},
                {"15","18"},
                {},
                {"2","3","6","8","23"},
                {"4","6","24"},
                {}
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ObjectSerializer. [ https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/89c2e8e76c68d0d0abe6a36b4e08ddc56979796f/src/org/apache/pig/impl/util/ObjectSerializer.java ] this awesome class allows you to easily serialise every kind of object to a String, that then you can save wherever you like. Example, having a sharedPreferences instance already created:

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putString( YOUR_OBJECT_KEY, ObjectSerializer.serialize(object) ).commit();
```

to get your object out from shared, you can call

```
object = (Object) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString( YOUR_OBJECT_KEY, null));
```

Note that if you care about performances (need to store huge amounts of data / heavy data - eg. images) both shared preferences and the mentioned approach may not be optimal

Answer (score 0):

You can use putStringSet in preferences

example preferences.putStringSet("key", Set);

Comment: can u explain it more i didnt understand the "SET" here going to developers  site  is also not helping me

Answer (score 0):

I have this class i made

```
public class SavedPreference 
{
    static final String PREF_USER_NAME = "username";
    static final String PREF_PASS = "password";

    static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ct)
    {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ct);
    }

    public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String userName) 
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_USER_NAME, userName);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static void eraseSavedPreference(Context ctx)
    {
        Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getUserName(Context ctx)
    {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_USER_NAME, "");
    }
}
```

**In your Case:**

In the setUserName you can change the code in there where you add the 2d array of yours and iterate them and add them using putString

Same as getting them as well